CPU usage high during synchronous RPC call
What version of gRPC and what language are you using?
gRPC : v1.37.1
protobuf : v3.15.2

What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and version?
Yocto dunfell

What runtime / compiler are you using (e.g. python version or version of gcc)
gnu 9.3

What did you do?

Called synchronous RPC call
The proto files are custom cannot be shared, but contains huge no of messages.

What did you expect to see?
CPU usage to be same as that of connection with a local server.
What did you see instead?
CPU usage when connecting to a local server is less, but with real server is high
cpu_high

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

This looks more like a support ticket than an actual question

You should try to use a more recent version of gRPC as it is possible that the issue doesn't occur there.
